# What is the default validity period of the email confirmation link in a ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

After users are registered, I have set up SendGrid to send a confirmation email to their email addresses. However, I do not know what is the length of time that the link in the confirmation email is available before it expires. At the same time, how can I modify the length of time?

Comment: I believe the default is 24hrs. Not sure how to extend/modify it though

Comment: Found it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#change-the-email-token-lifespan

Comment: `The default token lifespan of the Identity user tokens is one day.` Check the link to see how to change it

Comment: @Nkosi, if possible, please write a complete answer to OP.  This will help other folks who faces the same answer.